# Not understanding the 5th nullifier set by Muhammad ibn abd al Wahhab

Tags: islamic-basis

As per the 5th nullifier, it states that

"whoever hates something that was brought by the Messenger (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him), even if he complies with it, is a disbeliever."

but how can it be if that hate is naturally instilled in the heart and is a natural taste/preference of the individual?

I perfectly understand that ridiculing or crticizing outwardly is kufr, but I don't understand how can a person become a disbeliever if they hate (parts of) the Sharia despite of them forcing themselves to comply with it? 
Shouldn't the attempt and the effort be rewarded instead of one's inclinations of preferences?

I mean, what if Allah (swt) created that person that way? How can it be their fault for a characteristic that does not depend on them in the first place?

I can understand if the disliking translates into action only, but not otherwise as long as efforts are made.

Answer (score 1):

This is in accordance with what Allah (ﷻ) said:

> [Qur'an 47:9](https://quran.com/47/9) ذلك بأنهم كرهوا ما أنزل الله فأحبط أعمالهم  (That is because they disliked what Allah revealed, so He rendered worthless their deeds)

There's a difference between personal preference and disliking/hating what Allah (ﷻ) revealed. For example, you can personally dislike eating meat yourself but you cannot hate the fact that Allah (ﷻ) allowed meat for everyone. A woman can personally be against her husband taking a second wife but cannot hate the fact that it is halal for him and other Muslim men.

Could not the disbelievers say the same argument you're making, that "we just naturally don't like the rules of the Qur'an?" SubhanAllah. Reality is, a true believer in God would change his whole outlook on something just based on the guidance of God. And since God only gives rules that are good for us (and He did not create anyone to naturally hate His rules), we need to learn to give up what we love and hate for what He loves and hates (Al Wala Wal Bara). This is true belief.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is there's a difference between a person who, for example, prays in Jama'a but in their spare time logs in some social media and starts criticizing Islam and the person who may dislike a ruling but nevertheless acts upon it sincerely and tries their utmost to accept it, because in the former the person does something hidingly but it evolves into action (typing) while the latter does not translate this disliking into action even when alone and tries to be implementful on it. Do you get me?

Comment: What you said about some people saying "Allah made us dislike the Shari'a" is an example in which the disliking evolved into speech (same as action), and that's not the case I'm assessing

Comment: There's a difference between disliking and doing something according to it hidingly and disliking  but trying to overcome that disliking, please understand what I'm meaning.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you do something while you heart rejects it. Allah doesn't accept these deeds, clear from the Qur'an. If the person is **sincerely trying** to get over dislike, they will be guided since **Allah guides the sincere**. If they never get over their dislike, it means they were not sincere and/or do not believe. Fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

The statement means that you show others that you accept and love (believe in) Islam and deeply reject it (disbelieve) between you and yourself, and this is specially directed to **hypocrites** - **المنافقين** - **Munafiqeen**.

> وَإِذَا لَقُوا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا قَالُوا آمَنَّا وَإِذَا خَلَوْا إِلَى شَيَاطِينِهِمْ قَالُوا إِنَّا مَعَكُمْ إِنَّمَا نَحْنُ مُسْتَهْزِئُونَ [البقرة - 14]
>
> **And when they meet those who believe, they say, "We believe"; but when they are alone with their evil ones, they say, "Indeed, we are with you; we were only mockers."
>     [surt Al-Baqara - 14]**

There is no such thing as you hate Sharia, it either you believe or disbelieve. You might have some doubts about some things, so you search and work hard to clear things out, somethings have reasons clearly seen and others only known by ALLAH, so you accept it by the end in both cases and continue. So, hating here meaning you disbelieve, and that is the main point. It doesn't mean the act which is opposite to love.

Last thing is this might be a **shitan** thoughts, so just try to push them away and don't follow every thoughts.

Comment: I'm not talking about a person who, when alone, does not pray or sins as much as they can, that's not the case, I'm talking about the case in which one may not like Sharia naturally but they try sincerely to act upon it, even when alone, and the latter it entails sincerity, because of the person being alone

Comment: I am only explaining the meaning of the statement, not judging or reflecting it on you,  I say that your interpretation is not as what the 5th nullifier means.

Comment: In fact I asked for this reason.

Comment: this is something good, start learning more about Islam, Fiqh and Aqida, take your time, make sure you truly understand, and learn from good resources, books with high fidelity in Islam, and then you will be able to judge yourself.

Comment: The ayat entails a situation in which the Munafiqeen transform their disliking into action (speech with the evil ones), and that's different from the case I'm adressing.

Comment: Thank you for the answrr